# Why isn't the CSS id working in the dv? Have I made a mistake of some sort?

Tags: html, css

I'm new to both HTML and CCS (I've just started yesterday night) and have hit a snag. I'm having some trouble with using the id selector in the div; the background image is failing to appear. Please note that external ccs was used and the image in question exists in a separate folder. Also, the code seen below was made using notepad on my Microsoft computer.

Here's what I've got so far:

```css
#banner {
    background-image: url("../img/Sunflower.jpg");
    background-repeat: no repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

        <div id = "banner">

            <a href = "https://www.google.com/">Google Search</a>
            <br>
            <a href = "https://www.youtube.com/">YouTube</a>

            <h1>First Web Page</h1>

        </div>
```

Comment: Are you expecting a background image that isn't showing up?

Comment: You need to check if the image are in the corret directory, because i tried with an img and it works

Comment: Welcome to SO! I recommend all new users visit [ask] for tips about how to form questions in a way that best enables the community to provide assistance.  In this case, I would suggest you are missing a clear question statement.  _"I'm having some trouble with using the id selector in the div. "_ - what kind of trouble?  Is the image not appearing?  Is none of the CSS being applied at all?  Is it possible to include a [mcve] that would allow the community to reproduce the problem?  It would be best to include a statement of the expected behavior, the actual behavior and how they differ.

Comment: Yes, sorry if that was unclear @JenniferGoncalves.

Comment: That would be the location, right? If so, I tried using the full directory (‪"C:/Users/Rodriguez/OneDrive/Desktop/webpage/Sunflower.jpg") but that didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several things that can go wrong:

1. In your CSS, you used a relative URL. Usually, Images are transfered over the web via HTTP, so usually, we put relative paths only when we use a bundler for JavaScript/Css. I recommend you change your image path to `/img/Sunflower.jpg` This will make your web-browser request it at `<server_root>/img/Sunflower.jpg`
2. Maybe you didn't include the actual CSS path in the HTML file to make the browser actually fetch it. Please check the `<link>` tag

The code you've written is generally okay, so the problem is with your actual filesystem / understanding of server paths, so I recommend checking those out.

Here's a working example for you:

```css
#banner {
    background-image: url("http://via.placeholder.com/300");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div id="banner">

  <a href="https://www.google.com/">Google Search</a>
  <br>
  <a href="https://www.youtube.com/">YouTube</a>

  <h1>First Web Page</h1>

</div>
```

Comment: I figured it out; I followed your advice (hooray for constructive criticism) and watched some videos on directories to get a better grasp on server paths. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct and should work. Please consider the following.

1: Make sure you have the correct path of the image. Your path looks good from here, however, it is still hard to say because we don't know where you have saved the image.

2: Check and be sure that you have **linked** your CSS to your Html file if using the external CSS, or they are correctly placed in **style** tag if using internal CSS.
Thank you.

Comment: Thanks! I'll double check the directory, since it seems that my CSS works elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

are you using inline css or external css file, or make a separate folder to your media and use that objects by giving simple names like img1.png like that

Comment: I'm using an external ccs file and my photo is in a separate folder as well.

Answer (score 0):

- `no-repeat` instead of `no repeat`
- please remowe spaces around equation marks - I've never seen anybody formatting the code like that
- path to the image is most likely incorrect. Bear in mind `../` means one folder up relative to the css file
- did you include your css file in HTML file?

Comment: Oops, I missed that hyphen, haha. I also wasn't quite sure what those periods meant at first.

Answer (score 0):

Try add this line on header of HTML file:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />`

where "styles.css" is the name of your css file. Check if the css file is in the same folder too.